# Problemas Particiones ntfs

Tags: windows-8, ntfs, ntfs-3g

Buenas mi problema es que tengo una laptop con windows 8 pre instalado y le instale ubuntu en un dual boot todo funciona de maravilla excepto que la partición que deje para datos cuando intento guardarle algo en ubuntu funciona bien pero en el momento en que la reinicio y entro de nuevo a windows 8 los datos que guarda o almacene en ubuntu desaparecen de la partición de datos...alguien sabrá por que sucede esto o tendrá la solución???

Comment: English, please?

Comment: OK sorry...the problem is I have a laptop with windows 8 pre-install and I installed ubuntu whit it in dual boot...I've got a data partition in ntfs format to share things(music,pictures and data in general)The problem raise when a safe/store data in this partition with ubuntu then I restart the computer and I enter with windows 8 and this moment data that I stored whit ubuntu it disappears in windows 8

Answer (score 0):

This is because windows 8 does not read ext4 file system which ubuntu uses. See [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/112888/3-ways-to-access-your-linux-partitions-from-windows/) on how to read ext4 on windows.

Comment: Ok...but the problem I have it whit a pratition NTFS which I use to save data and share it between Windows and Ubuntu